# Accuracy and F-mesure for imbalanced datasets

Tags: unbalanced-classes, accuracy

I have 10 imbalanced datasets. Classes are : 1, 2, 3, ..., 10,11,12.

I used as evaluation metrics for my datasets accuracy and F-measure.

The F-messure of each class in each dataset is as below:

[image]

Is it wrong to use accuracy and F-measure as evaluation metrics in this case of datasets ? please see results in the following picture :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest against usign accuracy as a measure for model performance when working with unbalanced datasets. If 99% of the test set belongs to class A and my model always predicts class A, it will have a 99% accuracy despite being completely useless.

F-score (I assume F1-score) is fine as it makes a trade-off between precision and recall. If your predictions come with a probability, the area under the ROC curve (AUC) is an interesting measure, but I don't know if that's the case, so I would go for these three: precision, recall and F1-score. Use F1-score as the main reference, but dismiss any model with precision or recall below acceptable levels.

**NOTE:** Precision is the proportion of predicted positives that are actually positive. Recall is the amount of real positives that are identified as such. Unless there is a reason to do it otherwise, "positive" refers to the minority class

Comment: Large imbalance implies that one can only predict tendencies, not individual outcomes.  Tendencies = probabilities.  And use a proper accuracy scoring rule as discussed [here](http://fharrell.com/post/class-damage).